# What is the average age of carcinoma onset in shi tzu breed?

Tags: dogs, diseases

What is the average age of carcinoma onset in shi tzu breed?

I've tried googling a bit and couldn't find an answer for the intersection of the breed and this type of cancer.

Asking to understand if onset at age 6.5 is very early which might indicate environmental causes or a regular event.

Subject is male shi tsu with a throat tumor, suspected carcinoma (deceased).

Comment: This question is extremely broad. "Carcinoma" means any type of cancer, but different types of cancer are influenced by different factors (most notably cancer in the reproductive system). Cancer onset at 6.5 years of age doesn't sound notably early for some very common types of cancer like mammary tumors in unspayed females.

Comment: from wikipedia: "Carcinoma is a category of types of cancer that develop from epithelial cells", so it's not any type of cancer.

subject is male

Comment: Can you please add where exactly the cancer is situated or which organ was affected first?

Comment: Okay added some details.